# Defining answers

Tags: discussion, answers

How does one define an answer in Code Review?

Because we are just giving other people our code to review, how is it possible to define an "answer" to our "question". Is the answer just the comment with the best feedback?

Answer (score 5):

On Code Review, the answer is defined by the original poster. If he feels one answer is the canonical answer for his problem, he may accept it. It could also be the refactoring he chose to use from a number of equally good suggestions.

I don't see a problem with not having a direct Q->A mapping. As on Programmers.SE, sometimes the answer is simply, "Which post helped me the most?" There are many ways to indicate that other posts helped you as well, such as upvoting and bounties. And remember, you don't have to accept an answer at all if you feel that none warrent a check mark.

My personal preference is to accept the most helpful answer and upvote every answer that had merit.

Answer (score 3):

I would define "the answer" to a code review question as the answer that provided the most overall improvement in your code, and explanations of why specific parts needed improvement.

There could be several answers stating a lot of the same technical things, but which one provided you with the most insight on "why it was bad" and how to avoid similar situations in the future.